# Capistrano exit status

Tags: bash, capistrano3

How to avoid message of exit status?

I have many bash commands in my capistrano deploy script. At example:

```
capture "mkdir -p #{path_img_out}/original"
```

It calls many times and print output:

```
DEBUG [dd6ca4fa] Command: mkdir -p /home/deploy/www/test/shared/backups/20140307160556/public/system/images/files/original
DEBUG [dd6ca4fa] Finished in 0.098 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

How to hide this messages?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758774/capistrano-bash-ignore-command-exit-status

Comment: not work, because capistrano 3 has many changes

Comment: I'm not familiar with Capistrano, but `capture` sounds like it was very much meant to specifically capture and report the output.  Maybe there is a different command verb you can use?  Quick Googling suggests `execute` to my uninformed self.